# using ajax in rails on select dropdown

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I want to know how to do the following with Ruby/Rails as an exercise.

**index.html.erb**

```
<div id="selectionsPane">
  <label for="bootChooserControl">Boot style:</label>&nbsp;
  <select id="bootChooserControl" name="bootStyle"></select>
</div>
  <div id="productDetailPane">
  </div>
</div>
<div>
  <label>Item name:</label> <%= @boot.name %>
</div>
...
```

**boots.js**

```
$(function() {

  $('#bootChooserControl').load('/fetch_boot_style_options');

  $('#bootChooserControl').change(function(event){
    $.get(
      '/fetch_product_details',
      {style: $(event.target).val()},
      function(response) {
        $('#productDetailPane').html(response);
        $('[value=""]',event.target).remove();
      }
    );
  });
});
```

**boots_controller.rb**

```
def fetch_product_details
  @boot = Boot.where(sku: params[:style])
  render layout: false
end
```

**fetch_boot_style_options**

```
<option value="">&mdash; choose a style &mdash;</option>
<% @boots.each do |boot| %>
  <option value="<%= boot.sku %>"><%= boot.name %></option>
<% end %>
```

So I want `Item Name` populated with the correct boot name from my database. First, how do I use the `select` method to build my select button the Rails way?  Second, when the user selects a different item I want the `productDetailsPane` to update.  I don't know what I need to add to make this code Rails/AJAX ready.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside **boot.js** take out the following line: `$('#productDetailPane').html(response);`

**boots_controller.rb**

```
def fetch_product_details
  @boot = Boot.where(sku: params[:style]).first
  respond_to do |format|
    format.js
  end
end
```

**fetch_product_details.rb**

```
$('#productDetailPane').html('<%= j render "product_details" %>');
```

**_product_details.html.erb**

```
<div>
  <label>Item name:</label> <%= @boot.name %>
</div>
<div>
  <label>SKU:</label> <%= @boot.sku %>
</div>
<div>
  <label>Height:</label> <%= @boot.height %>
</div>
<div>
  <label>Colors:</label> <%= raw @boot.colors %>
</div>
<div>
  <label>Lining:</label> <%= @boot.lining %>
</div>
<div>
  <label>Today's price:</label> <%=  number_to_currency(@boot.price) %>
</div>
<div>
  <label>Features:</label> <%= raw @boot.features %>
</div>
<div align="center">
  <% if params[:style] != 'default' %>
    <%= image_tag 'photos/' + @boot.sku.to_s + '.png' %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

**routes.rb**

```
get '/fetch_boot_style_options' => 'boots#fetch_boot_style_options'
get '/fetch_product_details' => 'boots#fetch_product_details'
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`collection_select`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/collection_select) or [`select_tag`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/select_tag) for select menu in Rails way.
For populating your panel on selection of an item, you can use AJAX calls. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12885265/rails-populating-bootstrap-dropdown-with-ajax) is some resource, which uses JQuery's `$.ajax` action to make the call and do something on `success`ful execution. [This is another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14449315/change-content-based-on-dropdown-using-rails-ajax-and-jquery) detailed helpful answer to do similar task.

Good luck

Comment: Why isn't my `$('#productDetailPane').html(response);` line working?